# Kerberos SSO stopped working after Chrome update

Tags: google-chrome, single-sign-on, alfresco, kerberos

I'm running Alfresco site with Kerberos SSO and everything worked fine until last Chrome update (101.0.4951.54). Nothing changed in settings, IE still works, but in Chrome it prompts for credentials and doesn't accept them.
Does anyone know what has changed and how to make it work again?

Answer (score 4):

In our case, it is because of Security Policy parameter name change in new Chrome browser. https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408#noNonIncl

Chrome version 101 has removed the old policy name "AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist" and replaced with "AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist".

We had same issue with some other SAP web application and fixed the issue by replacing "AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist" with "AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist".

Example:
Key: \Software\Policies\Google\Chrome
Element Type: String (REG_SZ)
Element Name: AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist
Element Value: *.mycompany.com,*.trustedcompany.com